# JSON: iterate over a list of nested dictionaries

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, web-scraping

I have a huge list of dictionaries appended to the list from JSON in the manner below. I would like to access the "raw" from each dictionary and store it entire in a list of dictionary or a one huge dictionary. The final goal is to access the keys in the raw and convert them to dataframe columns using pandas.

> ```
>   results = [{
>   'FirstSentences': None,
>   'PrintableUri': '',
>   'hasHtmlVersion': False,
>   'hasMobileHtmlVersion': False,
>   'isRecommendation': False,
>   'isTopResult': False,
>   'parentResult': None,
>   'percentScore': 100.0,
>   'printableUriHighlights': [],
>   'rankingInfo': None,
>   'rating': 3.0,
>   'raw': {'distance': 1892760.0,
>    'distancekm': 1892.76,
>    'distancemi': 1176.11,
>    'objecttype': 'Account',
>    'objecttypename': 'Account',
>    'plocepp': 'False',
>    'plochpp': 'False',
>    'plocsdp': 'False'}}]
> ```

The code and the error I'm getting is as below:

```
response = [x['raw'] for x in results]

File "<ipython-input-90-64993f9dcd67>", line 1, in <module>
    response = [x['raw'] for x in results]

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

I have searched a lot of answers here but couldn't find the solution to my problem. Thanks a lot for the help in advance.

Comment: Your data has a typo....

Comment: missing a `}` to close out the first dictionary. with last line as `'plocsdp': 'False'}}]` your `response` code works fine.

Comment: Sorry guys, I made a typo while posting the question which I have corrected it now. The code still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to iterate through the list and for each element in the list, index the dictionary key 'raw'.
One simple way is to iterate over the list and and access the key 'raw' in the dictionary.

**Simple for loop method:**

```
response = []
for d in results:
    response.append(d['raw'])
```

**List comprehension method**

```
response = [d['raw'] for d in results]
```